# Syntax error in ansible while using handlers

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Below is my role task which copied the nginx conf and then reloads the service only when the shell command output of nginx -t contains "syntax is ok"

```
---
# tasks file for nginx
- name: Backup and update nginx configuration file
  template:
     src: templates/proxy.conf.j2
     dest: "{{ nginx_conf }}"
     backup: true
     owner: root
     group: root
     mode: 0644

  

- name: Running nginx -t to validate the config
  shell: 'nginx -t'
  register: command_output
  become: true
  notify: Reload nginx

- debug:
   var: command_output.stderr_lines

  handlers:
    - name: Reloading nginx service only if the syntax is ok
      systemd:
        name: nginx.service
        state: reloaded'
        when: command_output.stderr | regex_search("syntax is ok")
```

Below is the error msg while doing a syntax check, but if I comment out the handlers section, it works fine..

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: debug, handlers

The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/mint-ansible/nginx/tasks/main.yaml': line 20, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- debug:
  ^ here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlers belong into their own subdirectory in a role

```
- rolename
  |- tasks
  |  `- main.yml
  `- handlers
     `- main.yml
```

Comment: quick thing, if I move the handler code to separate dir, will the when condition work ?

when: command_output.stderr | regex_search("syntax is ok")

or shall I add this when condition in the 2nd task "name: Running nginx -t to validate the config" ??

Comment: No. You should ask a separate question about that. That would be too complex to be answered in comments.

Comment: But it wouldn't have worked the way you have it now anyway.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1118365/need-to-know-more-about-the-handlers-in-ansible