# Need to know more about the handlers in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Below is the tasks I have in my nginx role

```yaml
# tasks file for nginx
- name: Backup and update nginx configuration file
  template:
     src: templates/proxy.conf.j2
     dest: "{{ nginx_conf }}"
     backup: true
     owner: root
     group: root
     mode: 0644

- name: Running nginx -t to validate the config
  shell: 'nginx -t'
  register: command_output
  become: true
  notify: Reload nginx

- debug:
   var: command_output.stderr_lines
```

And I have a separate directory called handlers, which has below content.

```yaml
- name: Reloading nginx service only if the syntax is ok
  systemd:
    name: nginx.service
    state: reloaded'
    when: command_output.stderr | regex_search("syntax is ok")
```

Not sure, if the variable command_output will be read by the handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't, because `command_output` does not exist at the handler. You could modify the error handling of the check task and [define "changed"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed) with your condition, but in this case I'd just use the `validate` attribute in the [`template`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#parameter-validate) task and skip the rest.

```yaml
- name: Backup and update nginx configuration file
  template:
     src: templates/proxy.conf.j2
     dest: "{{ nginx_conf }}"
     backup: true
     owner: root
     group: root
     mode: 0644
     validate: nginx -t
     notify: Reload nginx
```

Note: The name of the handler needs to be changed to `Reload nginx` for this to work.

Comment: Will the validation work if the result of nginx -t if it has warnings ?

Comment: Good question. It depends on the return code of nginx, but I would assume yes.